# Save selected option from a dropdown box

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu

```
<form method="post">
  <select name="select_employee" id="select_employee">
    <?php $allemp=$this->AllEmployees; ?>
    <option selected value="">Select an employee..</option>
    <?php foreach($allemp as $row){ echo "<option value=".$row[ 'Id']. ">".$row[ 'Etunimi']. " - ". $row[ 'Sukunimi']. "</option>"; } ?>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="send" value="namesent">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button">
</form>
<br/>
<br/>
```

When I submit this form, I stay on the same page, but I want a the same time to keep the option selected previously option visible.. How can I do that?
I tried:

```
document.getElementById('select_employee').value = "<?php echo $_GET['select_employee'];?>";
```

But it did not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 $selected = ($row['Id'] == $_REQUEST['select_employee'])?'selected="selected"':'';
 echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row['Id'].'">'.$row['Etunimi'].' - '. $row['Sukunimi'].'</option>';
```

1. added a line above `echo options` `($selected = ($row['Id'] == $_REQUEST['select_employee'])?'selected="selected"':'';)`
2. Added `'.$selected.'` in side options.

Your code becomes : Copy paste below code instead of yours

```
<form method="post">
  <select name="select_employee" id="select_employee">
    <?php $allemp=$this->AllEmployees; ?>
    <option selected value="">Select an employee..</option>
    <?php foreach($allemp as $row){ 
      $selected = ($row['Id'] == $_REQUEST['select_employee'])?'selected="selected"':'';
     echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row['Id'].'">'.$row['Etunimi'].' - '. $row['Sukunimi'].'</option>';
 } ?>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="send" value="namesent">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button">
</form>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

here:

```
 foreach($allemp as $row){
     echo "<option " . (isset($_POST['select_employee']) && $_POST['select_employee'] == $row['Id'] ? ' selected ' : '') . " value=".$row['Id'].">".$row['Etunimi']." - ".$row['Sukunimi']."</option>";
}
```